# How to use PATCH method in react.js and typescript using react-query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-query

I want to use the PATCH method to update a list of items instead of PUT. I have be able to remove any CORS blockers. The issue is the response i receive when i update is `null` and all the forms are then replaced.

task.service.ts

```
 const update = async (id: any, { TaskName, TaskDescription, TaskOwner, TaskStatus, Skills, InitiativeLink, InitiativeName, TimeCommitment  }: Task) => {
    const response = await apiClient.patch<any>(`/tasks/${id}`, { TaskName, TaskDescription, TaskOwner, TaskStatus, Skills, InitiativeLink, InitiativeName, TimeCommitment  });
    return response.data;
};
```

OwnerHome.tsx

```
    const { isLoading: isUpdatingTask, mutate: updateTask } = useMutation(
    (putId: string) => {
        return TaskService.update(
            putId,
            {
                TaskName: putName,
                InitiativeName: putInitiativeName,
                TaskDescription: putDescription,
                TaskOwner: putOwner,
                InitiativeLink: putInitiativeLink,
                Skills: putSkills,
                TimeCommitment: putTimeCommitment,
                TaskStatus: putStatus,
            });
    },
    {
        onSuccess: (res) => {
            setPutResult(fortmatResponse(res));
        },
        onError: (err: any) => {
            setPutResult(fortmatResponse(err.response?.data || err));
        },
    },
);

useEffect(() => {
    if (isUpdatingTask) setGetResult('updating...');
}, [isUpdatingTask]);

function putData() {
    if (selectedItems[0]) {
        try {
            updateTask(selectedItems[0].ID);
            // setVisible(true);
            

        } catch (err) {
            setPutResult(fortmatResponse(err));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there needs to be some response from the api on success,  nor if you want to work with null response, you can just use the data you used to update to set setPutResult inside onSuccess

Comment: React-query doesn't care what your query function does (makes a put, post, database call, whatever). It just expects a promise for the data. If your API isn't returning data on a PATCH you need to fix the API.